# Координаты точки, делящей вектор на части

Tags: математика, вектор

Задача такова: нужно узнать координаты точки на отрезке. Для середины (1/2 отрезка) мы берем координаты начала и конца складываем, делим на два, а для 1/n начиная от точки. А есть ли формула?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Xn = Xa + (Xb - Xa) / n
Yn = Ya + (Yb - Ya) / n
```